# Create a third vector by alternating an element of the first and second vector

Tags: c, vector

In my problem, i have two vectors, for example:

```
v1[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
v2[4] = {5, 6, 7, 8};
```

I should create a third vector like this: `v3 = {1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8}`.
The size of vector can be also different.

```
int main () {
int n1, n2, i, j;
printf("elementi primo vettore: "); //number of elements first vect
scanf("%d", &n1);

printf("elementi secondo vettore: "); //number of elements second vect
scanf("%d", &n2);

int *vett1 = (int *)malloc(n1 * sizeof(int));
int *vett2 = (int *)malloc(n2 * sizeof(int)); 
int *vett3 = (int *)malloc((n1 + n2) * sizeof(int));

for(i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
    printf("primo vettore %d->", i);
    scanf("%d", &vett1[i]);
}

for(i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
    printf("secondo vettore %d->", i);
    scanf("%d", &vett2[i]);
}

int a = 0;
for(i = 0, j = 0; i < n1, j < n2; i++, j++) {
    if(i < n1) {
        vett3[a] = vett1[i];
        a++;
    }
    if(j < n2) {
        vett3[a] = vett2[j];
        a++;
    }
 }
}
```

But it works only if vectors have the same size, why?

Comment: `i < n1, j < n2` has the same meaning as `j < n2`.

Comment: Is `v2[2]` typo for `int v2[4]`? It has four initialisers. It's not clear what you are trying to place in the third vector. If it is the first and second vectors sequentially an easy way would be to have two loops. Copy one vector , then the other.

Comment: @WeatherVane  writing mistake, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma operator discards the first expression (`i < n1`) in this loop:

```
for(i = 0, j = 0; i < n1, j < n2; i++, j++) {
```

in consequence you loop `n2` times.

I will use a `while` loop instead:

```
int a = 0;
i = 0, j = 0;

while ((i < n1) || (j < n2))
{
    if (i < n1)
    {
        vett3[a++] = vett1[i++];
    }
    if (j < n2)
    {
        vett3[a++] = vett2[j++];
    }
}
```